# I get "Program has stopped " when running my java code

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

The following is the error:

I get this when. I Attempt to invoke virtual method `void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)` on a `null` object reference

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kerempc.odev, PID: 8573
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kerempc.odev/com.example.kerempc.odev.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.kerempc.odev.MainFragment.onCreateView(MainFragment.java:25)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1334)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7029)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2741)
```

What should I do?

Comment: You should fix up your question so its readable and people will want to answer. make sure to provide all relavent info

Comment: I added edits try and inlcude mire info cuz nobody knwos what you are doing and how we can help

Comment: How can I edit my question again @AlexanderTheGreat ?

Comment: press command F then type edit and teh button will be highlighted... It is right bellow the tags you added to your question

Comment: This is your problem 'java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference'... NullPointerException. You need to share your code which is responsible for this functionality.

Comment: I am trying to add my codes but it says "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: @RaufKeremSarı - Well just post the **relevant** part of your code.

Comment: Alternatively, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it ... and debug your code yourself based on the advice given.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest your `ListAdapter` object (somewhere in your code) is not instantiated right. As you can read the `ListAdapter` is null when you try to pass it to the `setAdapter()` method, that's why you get a `NullPointerException`.

It would be nice to post the code involving the adapter and the methods around it, so we can provide a more meaningful answer that solves your provlem.